# Recursive self join for chain counting

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 2 columns, each column is a FK to the same entity

Col1 and col2 are unique

I'm looking to create a query that recursively attempt a self join from Col2 -> Col1 based upon the IDs being the same on Col2 and Col1 between different rows

I cannot fathom this further than:

```
select *
from table as t1
join table as t2 on t1.col2 = t2.col1
```

That query only does a single join but i'd like to keep joining for as long as it is successful to retrieve a sum of successful joins

It's not possible for me to manually write the joins because there could potentially be none, one or many joins

Comment: The solution depends on **precise** MySQL version.

Comment: @Akina I am not using MySQL 8 ;)

Comment: Show sample source data (5-6 rows) and desired output for this data. PS. In general: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=51da80a0a521b86167d174acc01f1776

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=2466a88270ab5f09e1fa603b15280780

Expected output - 4

Row 1 joins to row 2 on c2.id = c1.id - The value of this is 1
Row 2 joins to row 3 on c2.id = c1.id - The value of this is 1
Row 3 joins to row 4 on c2.id = c1.id - The value of this is 1
Row 4 joins to row 5 on c2.id = c1.id - The value of this is 1

Add the values = 4

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive cte to achieve this.
Sample example

With recursive cte(id) as
(Select 1 as id from dual
Union all
Select id +1 from cte where id < 10)
Select * from cte;

Here values will recusively generate untill it reaches value of 10.